# How to convert from Float to Int in Haskell

Tags: haskell, type-conversion

I wrote a function in Haskell

```
toInt :: Float -> Int
toInt x = round $fromIntegral x
```

It is supposed to take in an Float and return the equivalent Int. I come from a C programming background, and in C, we could just cast it as an int.

However, in this case, I get the following compile error

```
No instance for (Integral Float)
arising from a use of `fromIntegral'
In the second argument of `($)', namely `fromIntegral x'
In the expression: round $ fromIntegral x
In an equation for `toInt': toInt x = round $ fromIntegral x
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Maybe you can try this `round 3.2 :: Int`.

Comment: If you need to find a function that you know the type like `Float -> Int` then your can search for functions of that type either on [Hayoo](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=Float+-%3E+Int) or [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Float+-%3E+Int+%2bbase&start=41#more)

Answer (score 22):

Your type annotation specifies that `x` should be a `Float`, which means it can't be a parameter to `fromIntegral` since that function takes an Integral.

You could instead just pass `x` to `round`:

```
toInt :: Float -> Int
toInt x = round x
```

which in turn can be slimmed down to:

```
toInt :: Float -> Int
toInt = round
```

which implies that you may be better off just using `round` to begin with, unless you have some specialized way of rounding.

Comment: That worked, thanks. I feel so silly after someone tells me a solution in Haskell haha